# How do you create routes with optional parameters in Sapper?

Tags: svelte, sapper

Let's say I have a `/foo` route. But sometimes people hit `/foo` with a language parameter: `/fr/foo`. And other times they might hit it with a language and a country: `/ca/fr/foo`

So I need a routing table like

```
[country]/[language]/foo 
[language]/foo 
/foo
```

That all direct to the same page.

Should I create a tree like this?

```
src/routes
└── [country]
    └── [language]
        └── foo.svelte
```

If that's the answer then how do I direct `[language]/foo` to `[country]/[language]/foo`?

I don't [see any optional params in the docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper.svelte.technology/blob/master/content/guide/02-routing.md)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Optional parameters aren't yet supported, but you can *almost* fake it with 'rest routes' (which I've just realised aren't yet documented ‍♂️) — `routes/[...parts]/foo.svelte` would render `foo.svelte` with a `page.params.parts` array that contained the preceding segments.

Unfortunately that doesn't match `/foo`, which it arguably should. I've raised an issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/765

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed /dashboard/reset/TOKEN/ID route. I made it worked with the following structure:

```
[acool@localhost cool-sapper-project]$ tree src/routes/
src/routes/
├── dashboard
│   ├── reset
│   │   └── [...parts].svelte
```

The above will make TOKEN and ID parameters available in `params` in your page:

```
<script context="module">
 export async function preload({ params }, session) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
}
</script>
```

Output:

```
{"parts":["2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12","1"]}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

For any one looking for an answer.
This is now supported.

```
src/routes
└── [country]
    └── [[language]]
        └── foo.svelte
```