# How to handle optional parameters in a svelte/sapper route?

Tags: svelte, sapper

With Svelte/Sapper, how to configure a root such as /[country]/about , country being optionnal ?
It should match /uk/about or /about for example (and not //about).

It looks like [something exists](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/pull/607) but it's not [documented](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Routing).

Comment: I had the same question, and it seems it's not supported as far as I can tell. There is another open SO question on this where Rich addresses the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403072/how-do-you-create-routes-with-optional-parameters-in-sapper and he links to a GH issue on the topic as well.